# How to redirect requests to a different web app hosted via Azure App Service

Tags: azure, redirect, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have two web apps hosted via Azure Web Services, with the URL `https://example1.azurewebsites.net` and `https://example2.azurewebsites.net` respectively.

What I am looking at is that I'd like to redirect requests for `example1` to `example2` without any code changes or redeployment. I am not too sure if Azure Web Service supports this kind of configurations out of the box. If so what'd be the best option for this?

Update:
To clarify, the URL needs to change to `example2` from `example1` for all the requests.

Comment: You can use slots https://stackify.com/azure-deployment-slots/ https://ruslany.net/2019/06/azure-app-service-deployment-slots-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: If someone hits example1, do you want to redirect them to example2 but the URL still read example1? Or do you want the redirect to change the URL in the browser to example2 after the redirect? Is this for all traffic?

Comment: Can you describe the effect you want in detail? Is it the one described by Rob Reagan, or something else?

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft not too sure if using slots sounds like an options but thanks for the idea there.

Comment: @RobReagan I'd like to have the URL changed as well, i.e. it'd become example2 instead. And yes this is for all traffic

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is to update your web.config with a redirect rule. You can even edit the web.config in the WebApp's SCM site without even having to FTP in or redeploy. [Here's the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/).

This code should do it, but I haven't tested it.

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.contoso.com/" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add: You said you haven't tested it. I just tested it, and this solution works.

Comment: How can this not be marked as the accepted answer  Spot on and the simplest solution.